# UIWebView difference between iOS 4 and iOS 5 on reading a pdf file

Tags: ios, webview

I have found a difference between iOS 4 and iOS 5 that caused an error in my code. When I create a `UIWebView`, it's also created a subview called `UIWebBrowserView` with a frame of size 577 x 533. Then, I load a PDF file in the `UIWebView` and here there's a different between iOS 4 and 5. In iOS 4, when the processing reaches the method "webViewDidFinishLoad:", the `UIWebBrowserView` still exists with frame 577 x 2947 (the size of the pdf, I suppose), and in iOS 5, the `UIWebBrowserView` doesn't exist anymore and in it's place there's a `UIWebPDFView` with frame 577 x 533 (here I was expecting a frame with size 577 x 2947). Finally, I cause an event and the views are as I expected (`UIWebBrowserView` with frame 577 x 2947 in iOS 4 and `UIWebPDFView` with frame 577 x 2947.4 in iOS 5).

The problem is that when the pdf file is loaded, when the processing reaches the method "webViewDidFinishLoad:" I'd like to put notes in the PDF file, but in this method `UIWebPDFView` is not yet with the real size of the pdf. If I just put the notes there they don’t appear. In iOS 4 it was working but in iOS 5 it's not working anymore. Anyone can help on how can I put the notes on the loading of webview?

Here is the code which shows that different behavior of both iOS and bellow the log.

```
ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIView *view;
    IBOutlet UIWebView * webView;
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

@end

ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [view bringSubviewToFront:webView];

    //Load view with a pdf file
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf_teste" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"text/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    //Log
    NSLog(@"On viewDidLoad: %@", [[webView viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]] description]);

    //Add a tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)view
{
    //Log
    NSLog(@"On webViewDidFinishLoad: %@", [[webView viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]] description]);

    //I’d like to insert the saved notes here.

}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //Log
    NSLog(@"On Tap Event: %@", [[webView viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]] description]);
}

@end
```

---

Log:

iOS 5.1

2012-03-30 14:24:28.075 WebViewTest[173:707] On viewDidLoad: >

2012-03-30 14:24:28.823 WebViewTest[173:707] On webViewDidFinishLoad: >
Mar 30 14:24:29 iPad2-de-ASDS WebViewTest[173] : OPDILG+TT857o00: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 38.

### 2012-03-30 14:24:47.167 WebViewTest[173:707] On Pan Event: >

iOS 4.3.5

2012-03-30 14:13:46.285 WebViewTest[823:607] On viewDidLoad: >

2012-03-30 14:13:47.049 WebViewTest[823:607] On webViewDidFinishLoad: >
Mar 30 14:13:47 BNBConsult01 WebViewTest[823] : OPDILG+TT857o00: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 38.

2012-03-30 14:14:48.199 WebViewTest[823:607] On Pan Event: >